# Output a result array with a grouped count of unique elements for a given array

Tags: javascript

If I have an array like this how can I loop through and push the counts into a a new array?
All help wlcomed!

```
    var Products = [
    ['Product A'],
    ['Product A'],
    ['Product A'],
    ['Product A'],
    ['Product A'],
    ['Product B'],
    ['Product B'],
    ['Product B'],
    ['Product B'],
    ['Product B'],
    ['Product B'],
    ['Product B'],
    ['Product B'],    
    ['Product B'],
    ['Old Product B'],
    ['Old Product B'],
    ['Old Product B'],
    ['Old Product B'],
    ['Old Product B'],
    ['Old Product]
         ];
```

End Goal :

```
        var UniqueProducts = [
    ['Product A',5],
    ['Product B',6],
    ['Old Product B',9]
     ];
```

Comment: Do you really need an array? I don't know what your end use is but it looks like having an object with product names as keys more logic.

Comment: The code would ultimately be a lot less gross and full of loops if you would accept the final result as an object like `var Products = {"Product A": 5, "Product B": 6}` (not to mention _way faster_)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Accomplished doing some simple coding with the expected result.
 http://jsfiddle.net/y9a8L/

```
function GroupBy(arrParam)
{
    var result = [];
    var lastItem = null;
    var item = null;
    var index = -1;
    for (var i = 0; i < arrParam.length ; i++ )
    {
        item = arrParam[i][0];
        if (lastItem != item)
        {
            result.push([item,1]);
            index++;
        }
        else
        {
            result[index][1]++;
        }
        lastItem = item
    }
    console.log(result)
}
GroupBy(Products);
```

Answer (score 5):

```
 var obj = {};
 for (var i = 0, l = Products.length; i < l; i++) {
   obj[Products[i][0]] = obj[Products[i][0]] || 0;
   obj[Products[i][0]] += 1;
 }
 console.log(obj);
```

See this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/XWSRE/1/

But before asking these kind of questions please Google once. This is very generic requirement and you can find solution in most of the places.

Comment: He is looking for an array, dont know if treating the response as an object will solve his problem, by the way I also liked the solution given

Comment: Should start out at 0 - your counts are off by one.

Comment: @dc5 It is in current iteration means the occurrence is already one right? :)

Comment: And then you immediately add one to it - i.e.: first iteration you set it to 1, then you increment it.  Final result in your fiddle shows: `'Old Product': 2`

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this:

```
var prod_array = []
for(p in Products) {
    prod_array[p] = (prod_array[p] ? 1 : prod_array[p] +1)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

@Exception's answer already provide a way to do it sensibly, but for your *exact* output, I loop through the object properties to convert to an array:

```
var u = {}, uniqueProducts = [];
Products.forEach(function (v) {
    if (u[v[0]]) {
        u[v[0]] += 1;
    } else {
        u[v[0]] = 1;
    }
});

for (var property in u) {
    if (u.hasOwnProperty(property)) {
        uniqueProducts.push([property, u[property]]);
    }
}

console.log(uniqueProducts);
```

See [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TP5QQ/).